# Data storage and replication in a private blockchain

Tags: private-blockchain, storage

What type of data is Ethereum storing (file? data row in DB)?

Where does it put it (theoreticaly it is stored in peers, does this mean every node must have a local db)?

How the peers of the p2p network get the recent copy of the blockchain?

how a peer learn that there is a new block created and need to be mined?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the client you are using. Geth (most popular Ethereum client) stores everything in a local leveldb which is a file based database. Generally it will put it into `~/.ethereum` unless you provide `--datadir` cli option.

Peers on the chain exchange information via a p2p protocol in a form of blocks that contain transactions. These are the then stored into leveldb once processed.

Everything you need to know about this process is explained in Ethereum Yellow Paper https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf